# How to register schema in the schema-registry based on input ID

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

By default `AVRO` schema registers to `schema-registry` and giving a randomly generated `ID`.

My requirement is that it generates the `ID` provided in the request. I have been going through the `schema-registry` [source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/storage/KafkaSchemaRegistry.java) and realized that they have not exposed any `API` for that.

Is my understanding correct? If not, please help me with `REST API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want Schema Registry register the Schema with the id you passed in the request.

Schema Registry does not expose any [API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/api.html) for this purposed to be called from clients, it assigns globals unique id to each registered schema, which are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing but not necessarily consecutive.

On Design Overview [section](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/design.html) explains this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming and same is mentioned in the provided link.